# Nx & Storybook: Cannot read property 'registerOptionsTransform' of undefined

Tags: angular, npm, angular-components, monorepo, nrwl-nx

[image]I am trying to install storybook on my workspace installing **@nrwl/storybook** and follow this [guideline](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/storybook/overview) but it seems there is an internal error:

```
Cannot read property 'registerOptionsTransform' of undefined
```

after the command

```
nx g @nrwl/angular:storybook-configuration project-name


nx report

>  NX  Report complete - copy this into the issue template

  Node : 14.16.0
  OS   : darwin x64
  npm  : 6.14.11

  nx : Not Found
  @nrwl/angular : 12.0.8
  @nrwl/cli : 12.0.8
  @nrwl/cypress : 12.0.8
  @nrwl/devkit : 12.0.8
  @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : 12.0.8
  @nrwl/express : Not Found
  @nrwl/jest : 12.0.8
  @nrwl/linter : 12.0.8
  @nrwl/nest : Not Found
  @nrwl/next : Not Found
  @nrwl/node : Not Found
  @nrwl/react : Not Found
  @nrwl/schematics : Not Found
  @nrwl/tao : 12.0.8
  @nrwl/web : Not Found
  @nrwl/workspace : 12.0.8
  @nrwl/storybook : 12.1.1
  @nrwl/gatsby : Not Found
  typescript : 4.0.7
```

Thanks in advance
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, during migrations Nx doesn't update @angular-devkit/schematics and at some point the old version breaks the workspace.
so it's enough to install:

```
npm i -D @angular-devkit/schematics@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing all the basic steps of upgrading to the latest @angular/cli, ensuring we have @Nrwl/nx and @Nrwl/angular, we updated our package.json file to ensure all @Nrwl/xxxx libraries were of the same version, in this example  11.1.5:

```
"@nrwl/angular": "11.1.5",
"@nrwl/cli": "11.1.5",
"@nrwl/cypress": "11.1.5",
"@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "11.1.5",
"@nrwl/jest": "11.1.5",
"@nrwl/tao": "11.1.5",
"@nrwl/workspace": "11.1.5",
```

After which we cleaned up and re-installed using:

```
rm -rf node_modules dist
npm install
```

We were then able to run the command that was previously causing the issue.

Here is our outpur from running the `nx report` command,  after the modification:

```
  Node : 10.24.1
  OS   : darwin x64
  npm  : 6.14.12
  
  nx : 12.0.8
  @nrwl/angular : 11.1.5
  @nrwl/cli : 11.1.5
  @nrwl/cypress : 11.1.5
  @nrwl/devkit : 11.1.5
  @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx : 11.1.5
  @nrwl/express : Not Found
  @nrwl/jest : 11.1.5
  @nrwl/linter : 11.1.5
  @nrwl/nest : Not Found
  @nrwl/next : Not Found
  @nrwl/node : Not Found
  @nrwl/react : Not Found
  @nrwl/schematics : Not Found
  @nrwl/tao : 11.1.5
  @nrwl/web : Not Found
  @nrwl/workspace : 11.1.5
  typescript : 4.0.7
```

Comment: I suggest, that you run the following, `nx report`, and provide here so we can view your package settings for @nrwl